# How to subscribe to CustomBox Modal close event

Tags: javascript, html

i have a modal implemented. I am currently using the FadeIn modal found here https://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v2.5.1/unify-main/shortcodes/shortcode-base-modals.html From looking at the code it's utilizing CustomBox found here http://dixso.github.io/custombox/

```
<a class="btn u-btn-primary" href="#modal1" data-modal-target="#modal1" data-modal-effect="fadein">Launch Modal
</a>

<!-- Demo modal window -->
<div id="modal1" class="text-left g-max-width-600 g-bg-white g-overflow-y-auto g-pa-20" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="Custombox.modal.close();">
    <i class="hs-icon hs-icon-close"></i>
  </button>
  <h4 class="g-mb-20">Modal title</h4>
  <p>Modal Body</p>
</div>
<!-- End Demo modal window -->
```

I can see that CustomBox has the event type Closed but i'm not sure how to properly subscribe to that event. I've added the following code but nothing happens. After the modal is closed.

```
document.addEventListener('custombox.close', function() {

});
```

May I ask how do i properly subscribe to CustomBox's close event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but you could just add a JavaScript function call to the `onclick` defined in your close button

```
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="Custombox.modal.close(); someCloseCallback();">
```

Comment: This solution is fine if they always click that close button but the modal can be closed if they click outside as well.